# Trouble with html input box

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a basic usd converter for practice in html/javascript.
However when I select the euro option it does the same as for the peso option.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Currency Converter</title>
        <style>

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="amount"> </input>
        <p>usd Contverted to</p> 
        <p class="output"> </p>
        <select id="select"> <option value="1">Peso's</option> <option value="2">Euro's</option> </select>
        <p id="answer"> is </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="run()"> 
        <script>
            function run() {
                var Amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
                if (select = 1) {
                    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "=-=-= " + Amount * 16.39  + "   =-=-=";
                } else if (select = 2) {
                    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "=-=-= " + Amount * 0.9  + "   =-=-=";
                } else {
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: check this url http://jsbin.com/nipelezugu/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are not getting value of **select**
- You are not comparing **select** value in **if** condition, make it as **select == 1** and **select == 2**

**[Complete solution here](http://jsbin.com/nipelezugu/edit?html,js,output)**

Change your javaScript function as below

```
function run() {
  var Amount=document.getElementById("amount").value;
  var select=document.getElementById("select").value;
  if (select == 1) {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "=-=-= " + Amount * 16.39  + "   =-=-=";
  } else if (select == 2) {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "=-=-= " + Amount * 0.9  + "   =-=-=";
  } else {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not comparing select,you are setting it.

```
   if (select == 1) {
       document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = ...
   } else if (select == 2) {
```

- = -> setting a value
- == -> comparing

Answer (score 1):

it should be `select == 1`
`select=1` will always return true, because this way you are simply assigning a value, not checking for equality